# Arrangeable profile of github repositories

Tags: web-apps, github

I'm looking for a web-app to better present my [Github](https://github.com/) profile. Being aware I cannot change the way Github itself presents it, it's of course acceptable having to point people to a different place (where the web-app is presenting it). I'd need especially to...

- group my many repositories e.g. by projects/topics
- present my profile in a way to make it interesting to other companies, e.g. those evaluating potential employees
- optionally enrich it with additional details not offered by Github
- details must be automatically updated from Github (i.e. using some Github API)

Solutions involving both GitHub, and third party websites would be acceptable.

### TL;DR

I have a reasonable number of repositories in my GitHub profile.

For the benefit of myself and/or others (including companies evaluating potential employees), how can I arrange them in a way that's easy to navigate? For example, "This group of git repos were to do with project X, while these git repos were to do with project Y, and here's my data scraping projects"?

I've tried searching for information on github profiles, and I came across [Why GitHub is not your CV](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/11/15/why-github-is-not-your-cv/) stating that (as of November 2013) you can't arrange your profile:

> You have no say about what you consider important, or worthwhile, or
>   interesting, or well-engineered, or valuable.

but I haven't found any other info on web applications for creating a nice profile.